# Entries in /proc/meminfo

Tags: linux, memory, procfs

I can make sense of most of the information contained in **/proc/meminfo** like total memory, buffers, cache etc. Could you tell me what do the less obvious ones like the ones listed below mean?

- AnonPages
- Mapped
- Slab
- NFS_Unstable
- Bounce
- VmallocTotal
- VmallocUsed
- VmallocChunk

If anyone is wondering, I am talking about the output of the linux command **cat /proc/meminfo**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The canonical source of this information is [/usr/src/linux/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt;hb=HEAD#l451).  Specifically,

> ```
>    AnonPages: Non-file backed pages mapped into userspace page tables
>       Mapped: files which have been mmaped, such as libraries
>         Slab: in-kernel data structures cache
> NFS_Unstable: NFS pages sent to the server, but not yet committed to stable
>         storage
>       Bounce: Memory used for block device "bounce buffers"
> VmallocTotal: total size of vmalloc memory area
>  VmallocUsed: amount of vmalloc area which is used
> VmallocChunk: largest contigious block of vmalloc area which is free
> ```

Comment: alternate link while kernel.org is down: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt

Comment: That seems to also be down, so here's another mirror: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt

Answer (score 16):

My understanding is as follows.
And I agree these numbers are hard to understand and showing inconsistent values.

- MemTotal

  ```
  = MemFree + Active + Inactive + Slab + PageTables + VmallocUsed + X
  (X : alloc_pages() (get_free_pages(), etc))
  ```

  But recent kernel's vmallocused value could be wrong.
  This is because it counts VM_xxx regions like VM_IOREMAP, VM_MAP,... other than VM_ALLOC area.

  VM_IOREMAP region can be mapping memory which can be outside of kernel's
  memory management, so the formula above can be not precise, or completely wrong.

  You can either do:

  - Check /proc/vmallocinfo to sort out all the entries and filter by yourself,
  - Modify fs/proc/mmu.c: get_vmalloc_info() to count regions only when
    if(vma->flags & VM_ALLOC)
- Active + Inactive

  ```
   = Buffers + Cached + SwapCached + AnonPages
  ```
- AnonPages

  ```
   = /proc/*/task/*/smaps anonymous area all sum
   (anonymous: no name|[heap]|/dev/zero|/dev/shm/*|[stack])
  ```

  Although I haven't been able to match these numbers. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885107/want-to-make-smaps-output-anonymous-region-sum-and-proc-meminfo-anonpages-to-mat) and help me if you have any clue.
- Total PageCache

  ```
   = Buffers + Cached + SwapCached
  ```
- Slab

  ```
   = SReclaimable + SUnreclaim
  ```

Answer (score 0):

From [RedHat](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-5-manual/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s2-proc-meminfo.html)

> VMallocTotal — The total amount of
>   memory, in kilobytes, of total
>   allocated virtual address space.
>   VMallocUsed — The total amount of
>   memory, in kilobytes, of used virtual
>   address space. VMallocChunk — The
>   largest contiguous block of memory, in
>   kilobytes, of available virtual
>   address space.

Comment: The VMallocUsed and VmallocChunk fields have been zeroed out since 4.4; see the commit to see why: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/a5ad88ce8c7fae7ddc72ee49a11a75aa837788e0