# How do I account for all of the memory in meminfo?

Tags: linux, memory, operating-system

I'm trying to understand how `meminfo` tracks memory. Here's what I'm looking at:

```
MemTotal:         341596 kB
MemFree:          147288 kB
Buffers:              56 kB
Cached:            46752 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:            86928 kB
Inactive:          41384 kB
Active(anon):      81532 kB
Inactive(anon):      288 kB
Active(file):       5396 kB
Inactive(file):    41096 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         81532 kB
Mapped:            87648 kB
Shmem:               316 kB
Slab:              11568 kB
SReclaimable:       2580 kB
SUnreclaim:         8988 kB
KernelStack:        3232 kB
PageTables:         5480 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      170796 kB
Committed_AS:    2692436 kB
VmallocTotal:     327680 kB
VmallocUsed:       59244 kB
VmallocChunk:     259076 kB
```

Here are my questions:

1) How can I account for all 341596kB of memory? Clearly 147288 are free. How can I account for the remaining memory? (short of writing a problem to solve the zero-subset-sum problem, I mean...)

2) Total inactive/active file memory is 46492, but `Mapped` is 87648. But, according to the [manual](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt;hb=HEAD#l451), it's

```
Mapped: files which have been mmaped, such as libraries
```

so.. how could there be more pages devoted to mapped files than there are files themselves?

**Due diligence** I've seen other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658411/entries-in-proc-meminfo) on SO related to this subject, but none that explains how to account for all the "used" memory here... Also, I've found the [Linux Kernel file](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt;hb=HEAD#l451) explaining `/proc/meminfo` -- it just doesn't seem to have the complete information I want.

Comment: This should probably be on the Unix/Linux StackExchange.